# Is it possible to use the 'Samsung Mobile Print' application with non-Samsung printers?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, printing

In my Samsung Galaxy S, there is an Samsung application called '**Samsung Mobile Print**'.

**Does this application require a Samsung printer ?** Or can it be used with other network or wi-fi printers too ?

Comment: Judging from other apps, I'd suspect the answer to be Samsung printers only.

That being said, HP has [ePrint][1], but Google's [Cloud Print][2] offers printing for older models of printers as well regardless of make.

[1]: http://h30495.www3.hp.com/about/eprint
[2]: http://www.google.com/support/cloudprint/

Comment: @Sparx: Make this an answer so I can upvote you :) Thanks for pointing me to the cloudprint from Google. I activated this, but in my gmail on my phone, I cannot find a 'Print' command or button. The documentation says `click the menu in the top right corner and select Print`, but I can't seem to find this. Am I looking in the wrong place ?

Comment: You need to go the mobile version of the website - Gmail or Google Docs and click the link there. Not in the default Gmail app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from other apps, I'd suspect the answer to be Samsung printers only. That being said, HP has [ePrint](http://h30495.www3.hp.com/about/eprint), but Google's [Cloud Print](http://google.com/support/cloudprint) offers printing for older models of printers as well regardless of make.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work with my HP Wireless printer :-(

At the moment Google cloud print requires a PC connected to the printer - hardware manufacturers are supposedly going to release printers with the software built in - but seeing as the software is nowhere near complete...it could be years and you'll need a new printer!

The HP printer has its own method for mobile printing though. HP have a system where you send a special address your documents as email attachments and the printer will print them.

The same printer works fine with iPhone directly. my wife just taps print and it prints her documents...

I think Android needs to get printing using existing standards ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

It does require a Samsung printer. From the Android Market description:

> Compatible with Samsung wireless and networked printers only

Thanks for mentioning the app. It did not come pre-installed on my phone and I do have a Samsung wireless printer.